# All ports are blocked

Tags: network

I'm trying to use proxyman on my mac. I found out that all ports are blocked but i can not understand why. I checked mac firewall, proxyman is allowed. Also I turned off VPN.

Comment: How did you find out that "all ports are blocked"? - I.e. what did you do and what kind of message did you get back to lead you to this conclusion?

Comment: I scanned ports with network app. It shows that ports are blocked. I installed proxyman on Windows and when I scan windows PC, network app shows that proxyman port is open.

Comment: And how does it look like locally on the Mac? - Can you connect to the port there? - If that is the case, and you have all local firewalls disabled - it sounds like you have an issue with a network device along the path.